# Error in running sample Spring annotation based program without any xml

Tags: spring

Hi I am trying to run a simple spring annotation based program without using any xml based configuration. I'm getting the error "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field". 
I learnt that using `@ComponentScan` spring scans the package mentioned and look for beans annotated.

Putting the code herein. My project is a maven project with hierarchy like `MyProject/src/java/SpringAnnotnDemo/autowireAnnotationBased`

There are three classed

1. Department.java
2. Employee.java
3. MainClass.java --> The main class

Department.java

```
package SpringAnnotnDemo.autowireAnnotationBased;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Department {
    private String department;
    public String getDeptName() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.department = deptName;
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
package SpringAnnotnDemo.autowireAnnotationBased;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Employee {
    private int eid;
    private String ename;

    @Autowired
    private Department department;

    public int getEid() {
        return eid;
    }

    public void setEid(int eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }

    public String getEname() {
        return ename;
    }

    public void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }
    public void showEployeeDetails() {
        System.out.println("Employee Id : " + eid);
        System.out.println("Employee Name : " + ename);
        department.setDeptName("Mechanical Engineering");
        System.out.println("Department : " + department.getDeptName());
    }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
package SpringAnnotnDemo.autowireAnnotationBased;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("SpringAnnotnDemo.autowireAnnotationBased")
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Employee.class);
        Employee emp = ctx.getBean(Employee.class);
        emp.setEid(374);
        emp.setEname("S.C.B");
        emp.showEployeeDetails();
    }
}
```

On running this simple program I am getting an error as below.

```
`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employee': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'department'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'SpringAnnotnDemo.autowireAnnotationBased.Department' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what am I missing. I want the most simplest form of using annotation based spring without using any xml based configuration.

Comment: use `MainClass` as the configuraiton not `Employee` as you have now in  your program.

Comment: Tried but that is also throwing the same error "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employee': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'department'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'SpringAnnotnDemo.autowireAnnotationBased.Department' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}"

Answer (score 2):

Change your this line

```
 ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Employee.class);
```

to this line

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainClass.class);
```

Comment: Tried but that is also throwing the same error "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employee': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'department'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'SpringAnnotnDemo.autowireAnnotationBased.Department' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}"

Comment: Then do this where you have written component over the department class . Specifiy a name with it. e.g  `@Component("demoObject")` Then where you have autowired it use another annotation with it `@Qualifier("demoObject")`. See if it works

Comment: It worked for the previous solution...I did a very silly mistake. Thanks all